# Differentiability and monotoncitiy

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

> Prove or give an opposite example:
>
> Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$,
>
> $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ differentiable with  $f'(x_0)=0$ and $ f'(x)\gt 0$ for all $x\neq x_0$. Then $f$ is strictly monotonic on $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm having trouble understanding how to solve this. I know for a monotonic function:

$\forall a,b \in \mathbb R$, $a\lt b \implies f(b)\gt f(a)$.

I'd like a hint to help solve this question

Comment: How can $f'(x_0)=0$ if $f'(x)>0\;\forall x\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Maybe OP means for all $x\neq x_0$, $f'(x)>0$? In which case OP can split the domain up into two intervals $(-\infty,x_0]$ and $[x_0,\infty)$, on each of which the function is strictly increasing because the derivative is positive on the interior of each interval.

Comment: @smcc exactly what it means

Comment: We have then that $f^{\prime}(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$. Then $f$ is increasing, hence for $b>a$, you have $f(b)\geq f(a)$. What can you say of $f(x)$, $x\in [a,b]$ if $f(b)=f(a)$ ?

Comment: The OP needs to clean up the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $f'(x) > \forall x \gt x_0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing 0n $(x_0, \infty)$. Now, because $f$ continuous it follows $f$ is strictly increasing on $[x_0, \infty)$. Similar,  $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty, x_0]$ therefore $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: It's okay to assume continuity even though it's not explicitly given? Is it because f is differentiable $\rightarrow$ f is continuous?

Comment: @Guest3232452435 Yes, f is differentiable implies f continuous

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Mean Value Theorem. (Consider $x\le x_0$ and $x\ge x_0$ separately.)

Comment: Could you give me another hint? So far using the mean value theorem I get that this is correct, although I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Well, if $a>b$, then either $a>b\ge x_0$ or $a\ge x_0>b$ or $x_0\ge a>b$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Prove the following with the mean value theorem, given that $x<y$:

- $f(x)\leq f(y)$
- if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x_0\in(x,y)$
- $f(x)<f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leq f(y)$ or $f(x)\leq f(\frac{x+y}{2})<f(y)$

Answer (score 0):

A more general claim is true:

**Claim.** Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be differentiable such that $f'(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Also assume that between any two points, there is at least one point with non-zero derivative.  Then $f$ is strictly increasing. *(So in principle many more than just one point is allowed to have zero derivative)*

*Proof.* Let $a,b\in \Bbb R$ with $a<b$. We want to show that $f(a)<f(b)$.
By assumption, there exists $c$ with $a<c<b$ and $f'(c)>0$. By definition of derivative, we have $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}h\approx f'(c)$ for small $h$, or more precisely and in particular: For all sufficiently small $h>0$, we have $\left|\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}h-f'(c)\right|<\frac12|f'(c)|$ and therefore $f(c+h)>f(c)$.  We may assume that $h<b-c$. So with $d=c+h<b$ we have $f(d)>f(c)$. By the intermediate value theorem, $f(c)-f(a)=(c-a)f'(\xi)$ and $f(b)-f(d)=(b-d)f'(\eta)$ with $a<\xi<c$ and $d<\eta<b$. This implies $$f(b)\ge f(d)>f(c)\ge f(a)$$
as desired.